# WPF Control actual size

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, size

I have this piece of XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="SizingTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="theLabel" Width="Auto">A very large label with a lot of text</Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the code behind, I'm trying to get the label's actual width, I thought

```
theLabel.ActualWidth
```

would do the trick, but after trying this code:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    double width = theLabel.ActualWidth;
}
```

The value of width is 0, I also checked with theLabel.Width, which returns NaN, theLabel.DesiredSize.Width, which also return 0. What can I use to find the real width of the label?

Thank you.

Comment: Could it be that the control has no ActualWidth because you're still in the constructor? The Windows hasn't actually been rendered yet. What if you move that code to, say, the Loaded event handler?

Comment: Ha! That did it. I always thought after InitializeComponent() everything should've already be rendered... thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ActualWidth` isn't set until the component's parents (and possible children) are laid out.

To get a component's `ActualWidth`, you'll need to wait for a layout pass to complete.  Listen to the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event, as its not called until after the first layout pass.

Comment: after looking for a solution for 45 minutes, this one finally works >.> thanks! (2 years later :P)